# Unresolved reference in class with "self" keyword

Tags: python, pycharm, self

I'm new at Python so I'm trying to create a class with some attributes inside of it. However, Pycharm gave me an Unresolved reference with the self usage. Here is my code:

```
from turtle import Turtle


class Pad:
    def __init__(self, is_player):
        self.is_player = is_player

    pad_body = Turtle()
    pad_body.penup()
    pad_body.shape("square")
    pad_body.shapesize(4, 1, 0)
    pad_body.color("white")

    if self.is_player:  # this is the place I get the error
        pad_body.setposition(-480, 0)
    else:
        pad_body.setposition(480, 0)
```

I'm not sure what am I missing in here. Why my self keyword doesn't work properly?

Comment: fix the indentation it will work

Comment: how many spaces are there? spaces are important in python. Right now it looks like that code is outside of `__init__`.

Comment: `self` is not a keyword; it's just a conventional name for the first parameter of an instance method, which in a method call will be bound to the object invoking the method.

Comment: Keywords are words that have special meaning to the *grammar*; `self` does not. You can use any name other than `self` as you like for the first parameter of an instance method, and Python will not care (though most people reading your code will :) ).

Comment: Thank you so much all of you for clarification, problem has been solved with the indentation problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me. (Proper Indentation)

```
from turtle import Turtle

class Pad:
    def __init__(self, is_player):
        self.is_player = is_player

        pad_body = Turtle()
        pad_body.penup()
        pad_body.shape("square")
        pad_body.shapesize(4, 1, 0)
        pad_body.color("white")

        if self.is_player:  # this is the place I get the error
            pad_body.setposition(-480, 0)
        else:
            pad_body.setposition(480, 0)
```